# Confusion about closed graph of a continuous map

Tags: general-topology

I've read from a book, it said if the graph of a map is closed, the the following assertion are equivalent:
(1) f is continuous
(2) the graph of f is connected
(3) the graph of f is path-connected

I know for a continuous function from R to R, its graph is closed, connected, path-connected, but I don't know how to prove the above statements in a general topological space and somehow I feel statements above may not be true. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In general you have to watch out: if $X$ is not Hausdorff, the graph of the identity function on $X$ is not closed. Always $X$ is the continuous image of $\Gamma(f)$ ( the graph of $f$), even if $f$ is not continuous, so $X$ need itself be (path-)connected for a graph on it to have that property.  If $f$ is continuous , $X$ and $\Gamma(f)$ are homeomorphic.